# In the docker alpine container, the nginx or mariadb or supervisor service cannot be started automatically (set via openrc)

Tags: docker, nginx, crash, supervisord, alpine-linux

I try to automatically install and start the "nginx" or "mariadb" or "supervisord" service in alpine cintainer(and already "`apk add openrc`")
But every time the container is restarted, the nginx service always shows crashed

I have executed "`rc-update add nginx default`"
But as long as the container is restarted, such as "`docker restart nginx-alpine`"
Then check after entering the container(`docker exec -it nginx-alpine sh`),command "`rc-status`" will show that the nginx service is "**crashed**",Instead of automatically starting at boot(restart)

my dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine

VOLUME /sys/fs/cgroup

RUN apk update; \
    apk add nginx openrc; \

    mkdir -p /run/openrc; \
    touch /run/openrc/softlevel; \
    /sbin/openrc 2>/dev/unll;\

    rc-update add nginx default;\
    rc-service nginx restart;

EXPOSE 80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRWIM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should start nginx off as a command in your docker image.
Can you please try rebuilding your Dockerfile as below and test it out?

```
FROM alpine

VOLUME /sys/fs/cgroup

RUN apk update; \
    apk add nginx openrc; \

    mkdir -p /run/openrc; \
    touch /run/openrc/softlevel; \
    /sbin/openrc 2>/dev/unll;\

    rc-update add nginx default;

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: I have tried this method, but it didn’t work either. Just after I executed "docker restart nginx-alpine", I go into the container again to check the "service nginx status", and it showed crashed.
Obviously the alpine images caused this reason

Comment: For the same reason, does CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"] only support nginx? Because I installed "mariadb" or "supervisord" services, the same situation happened....

Comment: I am not getting the same behavior as you. Can you exec into the container and attempt to manually start nginx? "docker run -it container:tag /bin/sh" then "rc-service nginx start" what do you see in the stdout?

Comment: Have you tested installing mariadb or supervisord to serve alpine images? You will encounter same problems